# Importing Members from ExpressionEngine

Tags: database, import, member

I'm experimenting with migrating a large site from EE to Craft to take advantage of the performance improvements for an upcoming site redesign. I see there are some plugins that work well to import entries via XML or CSV, but I have been unable to find a way to import members.

Obviously, the passwords are stored in the database encrypted for the EE logins which makes it a little more tricky. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Mike, I am about to do the same thing - move a site from EE to Craft - that involves a load members as well as content. Wondering if you came up with a working solution you might share. Also, you mention that you found XML/CSV import utilities but I do not see any in the official list of plugins on Craft. Thanks Roi

Comment: Anyone written a plugin that imports users from EE without passwords? Thanks
Lee

Comment: Could you post a question of your own with a little more information so somebody can try and provide you with a solution? You can reference this question if you feel it'll help.

Comment: Hi @user1070143! I converted your answer to a comment since it wasn't really an answer. As @Luke suggested, it'd be a great idea to post your own _question_ instead.

Answer (score 5):

Tricky is a mild way of putting it.

EE and Craft both hash (not encrypt) their passwords differently. Hashing differs from encryption in a few ways, but the most important one here is that hashing is not reversible, which means that the passwords cannot be recovered. Which, in turn, means that if you import the user information into Craft, the members still would all have to reset their passwords.

If that's okay, then you would be looking at a custom plugin that uses [the Users Service](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UsersService#saveUser-detail).